Is `flock` per-OFD or per-process-per-file?
man 2 flock on Linux says:
   [L1]
   Locks created by  flock()  are  associated  with  an  open  file  description  (see
   open(2)).   This  means  that  duplicate file descriptors (created by, for example,
   fork(2) or dup(2)) refer to the same lock, and this lock may  be  modified  or  re‐
   leased  using any of these file descriptors.  Furthermore, the lock is released ei‐
   ther by an explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these duplicate  file  descriptors,
   or when all such file descriptors have been closed.

   [L2]
   If  a process uses open(2) (or similar) to obtain more than one file descriptor for
   the same file, these file descriptors are treated independently by flock().  An at‐
   tempt to lock the file using one of these file descriptors may be denied by a  lock
   that the calling process has already placed via another file descriptor.

   [L3]
   A  process  may hold only one type of lock (shared or exclusive) on a file.  Subse‐
   quent flock() calls on an already locked file will convert an existing lock to  the
   new lock mode.

As I just learned, an open file description (OFD) is the entity created when you open a file. A file descriptor is a reference to an open file description - these are the integers that you actually pass to the system calls. You can have multiple file descriptors for the same OFD.
So, I read [L1] and [L2] as saying that flocks are per-OFD. From these paragraphs I would expect that if you try to LOCK_EX the same file twice, one call will block, regardless of whether those calls are in the same process or not. I expect that if you have a LOCK_SH lock on a file, and then you try to LOCK_EX it via a different OFD, that will block, again regardless of process boundaries.
But then [L3] seems to confuse things, it would seem to say that if you have a LOCK_SH file one OFD, then open it again in the same process, then LOCK_EX the second OFD... the first lock will be converted to an exclusive lock? This doesn't make any sense to me, there are now multiple "exclusive" locks for the same file..
Is the wording just sloppy here, or am I missing something about how this system works?
The FreeBSD man page doesn't say anything about OFDs, it just says:
   [B1]
   Locks are on files, not file descriptors.  That  is,  file  descriptors
   duplicated  through  dup(2)  or  fork(2)  do not result in multiple in-
   stances of a lock, but rather multiple references to a single lock.  If
   a process holding a lock on a file forks and the child  explicitly  un-
   locks the file, the parent will lose its lock.

If I just trust that wording, all of my understanding of [L1] and [L2] would go out of the window and I would indeed expect LOCK_EXing a file while the same process holds a LOCK_SH on that file to just upgrade the LOCK_SH - there is no problem with multiple exclusive locks because they are just references to the same lock.
